# Javascript external files, call function, undefined

Tags: javascript

Why do I get "undefined is not a function. The problem occurs when I want to create the Player variable in the main function. Everything worked before I used the onload function and the init WebGL and function main, didn't exist. Their content was just written in a script in the html file. So there is no problem with the creation of the new Player in the external file.
Somehow the function just does not exist.

Here is a part of my html file

```
<head>
    <script src="player.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
    <script src="main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body onload="initWebGL()">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="800" height="600"> </canvas>
</body>
```

my main.js

```
function initWebGL() {
     //...... 
    main();

   }

function main() {


    // Player
    var Player = new Player();
  //.....
```

Comment: Could you check where `undefined is not a function` is from? (which line?)

Comment: Make sure you don't have any syntax errors in your scripts.

Comment: the undefined is not a function occurs when i call var Player new Player(); If I unccoment this, I just get the same error one line later where i call var Camera = new Camera() which is defined in camera.js, which is not visible in the example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's giving you this error because you named your variable with an upercase, wich is the exact same name as your object Player, try changing your line:

```
var Player = new Player();
```

to

```
var player = new Player();
```

Look at [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/WFY5W/) to see it in action, the wrong button log your error in the console while the right button works !

**Edit**: in your comments, you talked about the same error with `var Camera = new Camera();` Just change it to `var camera = new Camera();` and your problem should be gone, don't forget to change your code accordingly.